# bash function definition gives syntax error

Tags: bash

I cannot define a bash function **only for** specific names **and when** I use `<function name>()` syntax **and when** I try to define it in the current shell (i.e. not in a subshell).

```sh
$ cat -n test.sh 
1   function f { true; }
2   
3   f() { true; }
4   
5   function make { true; }
6   
7   make() { true; }

$ function f { true; } && f() { true; } #OK

$ function make { true; } && make() { true; } #NG
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(`

$ bash test.sh #OK

$ source test.sh #NG
bash: test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `(`
bash: test.sh: line 7: `make() { true; }'
```

What's happening here? Is this an expected behavior? I believe, at least, this is not *syntax error near unexpected token `('* as the error message suggests.

---

**Environment**

```sh
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter. You can overwrite a system name. Your syntax looks fine. I'm still looking at it. I can define `function make { echo bar; }; make() { echo foo; }; make --version` at the command line and as expected, get `"foo"` back, so I'm a bit confused as to your error. Same `GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have yeas of experience on bash, but haven't encountered this problem until today...

Comment: @JohnKugelman Couldn't reproduce on `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)` on Raspberry Pi 3. So maybe the problem is due to my configuration but is it possible to customize bash not to accept specific names in the first place? I haven't modified the source code of bash.

Comment: I just went through man bash with `source` as the search term, I can't find anything there that explains it either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some sort of `make` alias that's getting triggered. I can reproduce this if I create an alias with purposeful syntax errors:

```
$ alias make='@)$*)@'
$ make() { true; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

Aliases only execute interactively. They're not active inside scripts, which explains why this only happens when you run the command by hand or with `source`.

Comment: Yes, I set `alias make='make --no-builtin-rules'` but didn't know it is expanded even in the context of function definitions. Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't know it either, and didn't expect it. I would have thought the parentheses would inhibit alias expansion, but nope!

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is described in [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61604266/8776746). I'm writing this answer to give solutions how to avoid the problem.

**Solution 1**

First undefine the alias and then define the function. Writing like this every time (for safety) seems troublesome, but this is a POSIX-compliant way.

```sh
unalias make
make() { true; }
```

**Solution 2**

Or use another form of function definitions. This is simple but [**not** POSIX-compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05).

```sh
function make { true; }
#or
function make() { true; }
```